# Laravel - How to use session username in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session

I am trying to display a table based on session username but I am getting the following error. When it is `id` it is working but when it is `username` it is not

```
SELECT tb_list.* FROM tb_list  
WHERE myusername = ".Session::get('username')."
```

*QueryException in Connection.php line 662: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 0 , 10' at line 2 (SQL: SELECT tb_list.* FROM tb_list WHERE username =  ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 0 , 10 )*

Thanks in advance

Lets say the session owner's username is john

```
Table with NO session
WHERE tb_list.task_id IS NOT NULL
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| task_id | username |  some_data  |    some_time    |
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------------+
|    1    |   john   |  some data  | 2015-02-29 1 pm |
|    2    |   jack   |  some data  | 2015-02-29 2 pm |
|    3    |   john   |  some data  | 2015-02-29 3 pm |
|    4    |   bill   |  some data  | 2015-02-29 4 pm |
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------------+

Table with john's session
WHERE username=".Session::get('username')."
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------------+
| task_id | username |  some_data  |    some_time    |
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------------+
|    1    |   john   |  some data  | 2015-02-29 1 pm |
|    3    |   john   |  some data  | 2015-02-29 3 pm |
+---------+----------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Why are you trying to get * from table and are you trying for logged in user? if yes you don't need to query just 

dd(Auth::user()) and get all information of logged in user.

Comment: It is to display rows which contains the same username with the session owner

Comment: So are not you looking for row with the session owner?

Comment: myusername is a selectbox field getting from the users table. So if any row contains the username same as the session owner, it will be displayed

Comment: Can you please explain in details what you want to do?

Comment: I draw a table. Please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you are missing single quotes.When you pass a string value into an sql query statement you have to put single quotes.
For example,

`SELECT tb_list.* FROM tb_list
WHERE myusername = '".Session::get('username')."';`

Try this one.

Comment: I tried yours. Now getting no error but the table is empty.

Comment: maybe you should try echo Session::get('username');

Comment: I tried this and worked out. return "  WHERE username = '".Auth::user()->username."' ";

Comment: Thank you. You inspired me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
return " WHERE username = '".Auth::user()->username."' ";
```

This worked out.